Can private members be accessed by an outside alias template?
Clang accepts accessing data-member d from within alias
template p, whereas GCC and MSVC reject it. Should this be
allowed or not? What does the standard have to say about it?
When accessing d indirectly by resolving the return-type of
template function q, with the help of template alias p,
all compilers reject the program. Is this the expected outcome?
Does that imply that Clang is simply wrong for accepting the
first case (defining a::m) ?
class a {
    int d;
    static const int m, n;
};
template<typename T>
using p = decltype(T::d);

const int a::m = sizeof(p<a>); // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope

template<typename T>
auto q() -> p<T>;

const int a::n = sizeof(q<a>()); // all nope

Demo

GCC's error message:
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T> using p = decltype (T::d)
[with T = a]':
<source>:8:28:   required from here
    8 | const int a::m = sizeof(p<a>);
      |                            ^
<source>:6:20: error: 'int a::d' is private within this context
    6 | using p = decltype(T::d);
      |                    ^
<source>:2:9: note: declared private here
    2 |     int d;
      |         ^

MSVC's error message:
<source>(6): error C2248: 'a::d': cannot access private member declared in
class 'a'
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'a::d'
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'a'
<source>(6): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(8): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'p<a>'
being compiled
<source>(8): error C2938: 'p' : Failed to specialize alias template


Side note: since this is a language-lawyer question, I observe that evaluation of a sizeof operator does not access the object, if any, designated by its operand.  Not in the spec's sense of that defined term.

This is tagged as C++11, but unless you are using an old version of MSVS the oldest version of the standard MSVS currently offers is C++14.

@JohnBollinger Unfortunately the term "accessibility" is used for whether or not lookup results are ill-formed because of private/protected specifiers. That meaning is completely distinct from the defined term "access", but it is understandable, why they may be mixed up (and I wouldn't be surprised if that happens in the standard as well). And then there is also access as in member access expression, a third meaning of the same word stem...

@NathanOliver Should I use both tags or just change it to c++14 only?

@user17732522, I understand the unfortunate use of terminology that fosters such confusion.  I wouldn't have said anything if this were not a language-lawyer question, but since it is an LL question, it is important to be precise with terminology.

I would target whatever standard you are actually using.  You should be using the same version with all compilers.

This is CWG 1554, which is currently open.
It is currently unclear whether the access control is checked in the context where the alias template is substituted or in the context of the alias template's definition.

Just to ensure that this answer is not completely dependent on an external source, I think it would help to put the notes from the 2012 and 2016 meetings into this answer as quotes.

So, the consensus from the October, 2012 meeting appears to be that lookup and access for alias templates should be in the definition context rather than in the context where they are used. But then, later in the November, 2014 meeting, a concern is raised that friendship cannot be granted to alias templates, which then is addressed in the February, 2016 meeting, where it is stated that: "The solution in both cases is to embed the declaration in a class and grant the class friendship." What do they mean with embedding the declartion of an alias template inside a class?

And why is this issue still open when it was originally raised all the way back in 2012?
